# Model serializer not called

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

(Migrating to `ember-data 1.0.0-beta.6`)

I have an:

```
App.Company = DS.Model.extend({...});
```

And an:

```
App.CompanySerializer = App.MetaRESTSerializer.extend({extractSingle : ...});
```

But `extractSingle` does not get called. But according to [the guide](https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/TRANSITION.md#per-type-serializers), `Everything is wired up by naming`. Why is this not working then?

Comment: Can you show your usage of the store for finding the record?  Or are you perchance finding records?

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting multiple records from the server, you should reimplement `extractArray`.

Have a look at the [ember-data API](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.RESTSerializer.html#method_extractArray) for an example.